# R[x]-modules defined by a matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm studying about modules over EDs and am experiencing difficulties in understanding the concept.

**Example:** Given a field $F$ and a square matrix $A$ over $F$ then $F[A]$ is an $F[x]-$module with

$ x.p(A) = (xp)(A) $,

where $p(x)$ is in $F[x]$.

This is reasonable as it satisfies all the module axioms.

What follows is a remark that in general $F[A]$ is a different module to the $F[x]-$module defined by $A$ with example given when we take the matrix $A$ to equal

$1 0 0 $

$0 1 1$

$0 0 1$

and we take our field to be $R$

**Q1** What does "$F[A]$ as a module" mean?

Do we define scalar multiplication as $ p(x).v = p(A)v$?

**Q2** The remark says that "the $R[x]-$module defined by $A$ is a $3$ dimensional vector space". Why is this true? Don't we need to have the inverse of every scalar for this to hold?

Thanks in advance

**Edit** Here is a picture:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jzuh.png)

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! What is an `ED`?

Comment: Hello, @Bernard , ED is short for Euclidean Domain

Comment: Your question is not fully clear Could you post a reference of a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm correct the book is trying to explain something simple in a very convoluted way. Suppose $F$ is a field and $A$ is an $n \times n $ matrix over $F$. We can then make the following two constructions:

First we can regard $A$ as a linear transformation $F^n \to F^n$. Using this we can turn $F^n$ into an $F[x]$-module as follows: given $f(x) = a_n x^n + \cdots + a_0$ we set $f(x) \cdot v = a_n A^n(v) + \cdots + a_1 A(v) + a_0 (v)$. In particular, $x$ acts on a vector $v$ by $x \cdot v = A(v)$, i.e. just applying the matrix $A$ to the vector $v$.

Secondly we can turn $F[A]$ into an $F[x]$-module. Now we want to say how $x$ should act on a polynomial of the form $G(A) = a_n A^n + \cdots + a_1 A + a_0$ and we do this by saying that $x$ should act as multiplication by $A$, i.e.
$$x \cdot G(A) = a_n A^{n+1} + \cdots + a_1 A^2 + a_0 A.$$

All the book is saying is that these two constructions are not the same thing -- in the first one we are giving $F^n$ a $F[x]$-module structure, while in the second one we are giving $F[A]$ an $F[x]$-module structure.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathrm{F}[x]$ is the polynomial ring in one variable $x$ over the field $\mathrm{F}$. Let $n$ be a positive integer. Via
$$
    \mathrm{F}[x] \times \mathrm{End}(\mathrm{F}^n) \to \mathrm{End}(\mathrm{F}^n) \, , \quad (p, M) \mapsto p(M)
$$
we get an action of $\mathrm{F}[x]$ on the ring $\mathrm{End}(\mathrm{F}^n)$ of linear endomorphisms of $\mathrm{F}^n$. This action turns $\mathrm{End}(\mathrm{F}^n)$ into an $F[x]$-module.

Now your square matrix $A$ can be seen as an endomorphism of $\mathrm{F}^n$ and $\mathrm{F}[A]$ denotes the smallest submodule of $\mathrm{End}(\mathrm{F}^n)$ which contains $A$ and the field $\mathrm{F}$. This answers your question Q1. In particular $\mathrm{F}[A]$ is a subvector space of $\mathrm{End}(\mathrm{F}^n)$. Now concerning your question Q2: $\mathbb{R}[A]$ is a two-dimensional
vector space. In fact, you can see easily see that $id$ and $A$ are linearly independent in $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. You can compute that $A^2 = 2A-id$ and thus  for all $k \geq 2$ we have
$$
A^k = 2A^{k-1}-A^{k-2} \, .
$$
Hence,
$\{ id, A \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}[A]$. On the other hand, via
$$
\mathrm{F}[x] \times \mathrm{F}^n \to \mathrm{F}^n \, , \quad (p, v) \mapsto p(A) \cdot v \, ,
$$
$\mathrm{F}^n$ is an $\mathrm{F}[x]$-module (and in fact a $\mathrm{F}[A]$-module). However, as a vector space, $\mathrm{F}^n$ is clearly $n$-dimensional. Thus in this way one has to understand "the
$\mathrm{F}[x]$-module defined by $A$".

Comment: Whoa, thanks for the explanation. Can you explain in details what is the main difference between a vector space and a module, please? I know that a module over a field is a vector space since we have inverses of each scalar and we can use the same arguments as for the vector space, but when can we say that a module is essentially a vector space? I am particularly interested in the cases where a module is defined by a matrix and a linear transformation. Thank you in advance, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The axioms for a vector space (over a field) and a module (over a ring) are quite similar. Now, in your case you are interested in modules over the ring $\mathrm{F}[x]$. However, $\mathrm{F}[x]$ is in fact an algebra over the field $\mathrm{F}$, since $\mathrm{F} \cdot 1 \subset \mathrm{F}[x]$. Thus if you have an $\mathrm{F}[x]$-module $M$, then the action $\mathrm{F}[x] \times M \to M$ restricts to an action $\mathrm{F} \times M \to M$ and thus $M$ has in a natural way the structure of a $\mathrm{F}$-vector space. I hope that this clarifies your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite see what you are getting at here. What is the case is that given an $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ over a commutative ring $R$, one can make the space $R^n$ (interpreted as row vectors of length $n$) into an $R[X]$-module
(a right module) by defining
$$\mathbf{v}.f(X)=\mathbf{v}f(A).$$
On the left one has the module operation ($f$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $R$) and on the right one has matrix multiplication
($f(A)$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix and so $\mathbf{v}f(A)$ is a length-$n$ row vector).

In your example $(1,0,0)\cdot X=(1,0,0)$, also $(0,1,0)\cdot X=(0,1,1)$ and $(0,0,1)\cdot X=(0,0,1)$. If $R=F$ is a field, this module is a three-dimensional vector space over $F$.

Comment: Dear @LordShark sorry if I am becoming too annoying. I am just unsure about the difference in the 2 definitions and why this is a 3-dimensional vector space. When we say that M is the **R**[x]-module defined by A, we say that we define the scalar multiplication as follows and then can we say something about the elements of M except that they form an abelian group?